# Undefined reference errors to all functions whe trying to statically link my SDL2-based program

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, static-linking

I want to link statically my C++ SDL2-based program, but it's not working as expected.

I already placed all headers files, my program and the `libSDL2main.a` file in a single folder. Then I tried to compile the program.

`g++ -c Static_linking.cpp -o static.o` works perfectly

`g++ static.o libSDL2main.a -o static` but this line gives me a lot of linking errors.

```
/usr/bin/ld: static.o: in function `main':
Static_linking.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
/usr/bin/ld: Static_linking.cpp:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: Static_linking.cpp:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateRenderer'
/usr/bin/ld: Static_linking.cpp:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor'
/usr/bin/ld: Static_linking.cpp:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `SDL_RenderClear'
/usr/bin/ld: Static_linking.cpp:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `SDL_RenderPresent'
/usr/bin/ld: Static_linking.cpp:(.text+0x9d): undefined reference to `SDL_Delay'
/usr/bin/ld: Static_linking.cpp:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: Static_linking.cpp:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyRenderer'
/usr/bin/ld: Static_linking.cpp:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

PS: Everything works when I link the program dynamically with:
`g++ Static_linking.cpp -lSDL2 -o static`

**New Discovery**

I was wrong, in fact there is a file called `libSDL2.a` (I don't know why it didn't show up for me on Files when I searched for it).

Although when I tried `g++ static.o libSDL2main.a libSDL2.a -o static` it gives me a message error so scary and big that I will only show here the beggining.

```
/usr/bin/ld: libSDL2.a(SDL_alsa_audio.o): in function `ALSA_Init':
(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_open'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x51): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_close'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_writei'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_readi'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x7b): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_recover'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x89): undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x97): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_copy'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_any'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xb3): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xc1): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xeb): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xf9): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near'
```

Comment: have you tried using the `-L` flag to specify a directory to look for your `.a` files?

Comment: I tried and it doesn't change anything unfortunely     `g++ static.o libSDL2main.a -o static -L /home/daniel/'Área de trabalho'/SDL2_Linking`. But I think that using the `-L` flag doesn't matter because all the files are in the same directory.

Comment: @d.olinger dynamic libraries have dependency table and pull everything required recursively. Static libraries don't have that and you'll have link with every dependency SDL2 have. In that particular case your problem is depending on `asound`, so you need to link with that too. For windows resulting dependency list is very long. However modern SDL2 defaults to late linking and should not have direct dependencies on many things (including asound). E.g. my self-built SDL2 only depends on libc, libm, libdl, libdbus and libpthread. Why do you need static SDL2 though?

Comment: SDL2 has a pkg-config file that specifies the exact flags that you should use. Get them by running `pkg-config sdl2 --libs --static`.

Comment: `pkg-config sdl2 --libs --static` gives me `-pthread -lSDL2 -lrt -lunwind-generic -lunwind -lglib-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -libus-1.0 -ldbus-1 -ldl -lm -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -pthread -lSDL2`. Then I tried to compile the program `g++ static.o -o static_2 -pthread -lSDL2 -lrt -lunwind-generic [...]` and the program was compiled successfully. Althout I think it didn't work because the file size is smaller than the size of the dynamically linked program.

Comment: @d.olinger you can always check with `ldd ./your_executable` or `readelf -d ./your_executable`. But yes, it is very likely your linking is dynamic, as nothing in this command line specifies static.

Comment: @keltar thanks. I don't need, I only wanted to learn how to do it, so I would be capable if I needed.

Comment: @d.olinger have you figured it out? Distros often have much more dependencies because they control entire package list of your system. Consider building SDL yourself, with `*_SHARED` flags turned on (it is, by default), that'll leave dependency resolution to runtime. Then just link staticly SDL2 and dynamicly with libc/libdl (e.g. `/path/to/your/libSDL2.a -lc -ldl`, but there are other ways). That way you also could build debug version of SDL2 that may help debugging when things to wrong.